# SQL combining data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables...

```
+-----------+-----------+
| employees | positions |
+-----------+-----------+
| id        | id        |
| fname     | pos       |
| lname     |           |
| hphone    |           |
| cphone    |           |
| email     |           |
| posid     |           |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to create a form to add a new employee and have a dropdown for the position 
so that you pick from a position that is listed in the positions table

I know how to make the dropdown box but i am not sure how to setup the sql and
how to save it as a new record...can someone please help me?

The code im using for the dropdown is a function called getpos and it is...

```
function getpos(){
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,pos FROM positions"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){ 
$select= '<select name="select">';   
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
  $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['pos'].'</option>'; 
  } 
} 
$select.='</select>'; 
echo $select;
}
```

it works fine...to call it i use

this is the SQL i thought about...is it correct?

```
SELECT employees.id, employees.fname, employees.lname, employees.hphone,
employees.cphone, employees.email, employees.posid
FROM employees
INNER JOIN
positions ON positions.posid = employees.posid
```

Comment: You aren't making a dropdown in SQL, are you?  You need to tell us what languages, frameworks, etc., you are using before we can help you.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of SQL? Sounds like you are asking how to insert dummy data in your simple table...

Comment: @ps2goat true but more than that we can just give him the code to do it in say asp.net or c# winforms. You need to have demonstrated at least a basic knowledge of the question you are asking.

Comment: sorry...i am using linux with mysql and PHP for the framework...

Comment: `SELECT id, pos FROM positions ORDER BY pos DESC;` to populate the the drop down list. Then you use the values from your form to insert into you database. `INSERT INTO (fname, flname, hphone,cphone,email, posid FROM employees VALUES (....values from the form ...);` One of the variable you insert is the ID from positions.

Comment: @user3251779 Change SELECT query into: `SELECT id, pos FROM positions;`

Comment: but...when I display the data...after adding it to the database..how do i make sure it shows the position..and not the position"id" that was saved with i saved the form?

Comment: What you do is use the ID because this is the primary key of the table positions. And it is also the foreign key from table employees. I don't know which method you using for action (GET/POST). But on the next page you will retrieve $_GET['id'] and insert that into your other table employees (posid).

Comment: If you want to see the name of the position you do a join. `SELECT position.name, employees.fname, employees.flname, employees.hphone, employees.cphone,employees.email FROM employees JOIN positions ON employees.posid = posistion.id;` And if you do add `WHERE pos LIKE = 'manager' you will be able to search for employees with the position of manager in you database.

Comment: @user3251779 INNER JOIN would also give the same result. But then you matching two ways. I see no reason to do that so my recommendation would be `JOIN`. But this is not useful for populating your drop down list OR for inserting into to the database.

Comment: @user3251779 if you question is solved could you please upvote and or accept my answer below?

Comment: @logixologist look how much time and effort asking that question saved us!

Comment: @ps2goat glad I could be of help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT id, pos FROM positions ORDER BY pos DESC;
```

to populate the the drop down list. The positions will be given in descending order.

I don't know which method you using for the form action (GET/POST). But on the next page you will retrieve `$_GET['id']` or `$_POST['id']` and insert that into your other table employees (posid).

Then you use the values from your form to insert into you database.

```
INSERT INTO (fname, flname, hphone,cphone,email, posid 
FROM employees 
VALUES (....values from the form ...);
```

One of the variable you want to insert is the ID from positions.

If you want to SELECT the data from the database in order to display them in a table for instance you could use this query:

```
SELECT position.name, employees.fname, employees.flname,
employees.hphone, employees.cphone,employees.email 
FROM employees JOIN positions 
ON employees.posid = posistion.id;
```

Comment: @user3251779 is you question solved with the answer above? Or do you still need help?

Comment: @user3251779 your welcome. I don't know if are familiar with the upvote / accept option on stackoverflow. You can upvote / accept an answer if you feel it helped solving you question. You can do that by clicking on the arrow or place a check mark on the left hand side of the answer you like. I would really appreciate it if you would do that. In turn I will also increase you own reputation if you accept answers you like. Anyway good luck with you project.